# Stream videos in client app using Ajax and java Restlet

Tags: java, jquery, html, video-streaming, restlet

Hi I want to stream videos in client app but videos are located in server app. I am using java Restlet and Jquery Ajax to connect client app to server app. Through Ajax call i am connecting to Restlet. I don't know how to send response to ajax after streaming video from server side, how ajax receives response and how to play video in browser.  Can any one help me to handle this.

Here is my code

**Html:**

```html
<button id="playVideo" class="btn-primary">PlayVideo</button>
<video id="videoTab" height="300" width="500" style="display: none" controls ></video>
```

**Ajax Call to server**

```
    $('#playVideo').click(function (){
        var jsonObj = {};
        jsonObj.userId = "siva";
        jsonObj.file = "sample.mp4";
        //console.log("json obje :"+ JSON.stringify(jsonObj))
        // Rest call to play videos.
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : config.streamVideo,
            //dataType : 'json',
            data : JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
            contentType : "application/json",
            mimeType : "video/mp4",
            processData : false,
            crossDomain : true,
            success : function(result) {
                //console.log("login result : " + JSON.stringify(result));
                if (result) {
                    console.log("success.....");
                    srcPath = "data:video/mp4;"+result;
                    $('#videoTab').attr('src', srcPath);
                    $('#videoTab').css('display', 'block');
                    $('#videoTab').attr('autoplay', true);
                } else {
                    alert('failed...');
                }
            },
            error : function(){
                alert('error')
            }
        });
    });
```

**RestletCode:**

```
@Get
public InputRepresentation handleRequest(Representation entity) throws IOException,        ResourceException {
// Set response headers
Series<Header> responseHeaders = (Series<Header>)    getResponse().getAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers");
if (responseHeaders == null) {
  responseHeaders = new Series<Header>(Header.class);
  getResponse().getAttributes().put("org.restlet.http.headers", responseHeaders);
}
responseHeaders.add(new Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"));

logger.debug("+++++++++++++++++++Entered in play video restlet +++++++++++++++");
// Convert Rest type request to Servlet request
httpServletRequest = ServletUtils.getRequest(getRequest());
// Get Servlet context object.
sc = httpServletRequest.getServletContext();
// Get input file path.
logger.debug("------->getRealPath " + sc.getRealPath("/"));
String filePath = sc.getRealPath("/") + "WEB-INF\\data\\videos\\sample.mp4";

final File file = new File(filePath);
if (file.exists()) {
  logger.debug("Requested file path : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
  logger.debug("inputRepresentation :" + inputRepresentation);
  fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  inputRepresentation = new InputRepresentation(new InputStream() {
    private boolean waited = false;

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
      waited = false;

      // read the next byte of the FileInputStream, when reaching the
      // end of the file, wait for 2 seconds and try again, in case
      // the file was not completely created yet
      while (true) {
        byte[] b = new byte[1];

        if (fis.read(b, 0, 1) > 0) {
          return b[0] + 256;
        } else {
          if (waited) {
            return -1;
          } else {
            try {
              Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
              logger.error("Exception while streaming video : ", ex);
            }
            waited = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }, MediaType.VIDEO_MP4);
} else {
  logger.debug("Requested file not found : " + filePath);
}
//logger.debug("inputRepresentation :");
return inputRepresentation;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comment, here is my understanding of what you should do.
I would not send json to a resource in order to get something, I would just send a simple GET request.
You need:

- a resource that returns the file of a video according to its identifier. For the matter of illustration, let's say its url template is */videos/{videoid}*
- a web page that contains the links, and the empty video player
- some javascript that set the "src" attribute video player with the url defined above: */videos/{videoid}*. The way you compute the *videoid* is your own business.

Here is the server code:

- the Restlet application, that defines the URI templates

> ```
> @Override
> public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
>
>     Router router = new Router(getContext());
>
>     // attaches the resource that represents a video, according to its identifier
>     router.attach("/videos/{videoid}", VideoServerResource.class);
>     // ... other instructions
>
>     return router;
> }
> ```

- the video server resource:

> ```
> public class VideoServerResource extends ServerResource {
>
>     private File video;
>     @Override
>     protected void doInit() throws ResourceException {
>         String videoId = getAttribute("videoid");
>         // Compute path
>         String path = "/tmp/" + videoId + ".mp4";
>         video = new File(path);
>         // takes care of not found status responses.
>         setExisting(video.isFile());
>     }
>
>     @Get("mp4")
>     public File represent() {
>         return video;
>     }
> }
> ```

Here is the client code. This is a sample Web page, with an empty video player. When clicking on the button, the video player is asked to play the *http://example.com:9000/videos/testvideo* video. In your case, the value *testvideo* is simply deduced from the link the user click on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
    <script src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
$('#playVideo').click(function (){
    srcPath = "http://127.0.0.1:9000/videos/testvideo";
    $('#videoTab').attr('src', srcPath);
    $('#videoTab').css('display', 'block');
    $('#videoTab').attr('autoplay', true);
});
    </script>
</head>
<body> 

<button id="playVideo" class="btn-primary">PlayVideo</button>
<video id="videoTab" height="300" width="500" style="display: none" controls ></video>
</body> 
</html>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for response sir @Thierry Boileau . I have one doubt in your explanation. How to receive response(given by restlet) in ajax call and how it pass to HTML Video tag?. Here client and server are different applications in my scenario.

Comment: Hi, I don't know what kind of scenario you want to set up. But, in my sample code, the web page contains the HTML code for a video player that serves a video reachable on the "/video" URL (it could be on another domain). There is no ajax code, just a pure simple web player that reads the video given its url. Does it fit your need, or could you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: sir, my requirement is, When a user logged in on client app there will be list of video links in a web page those links doesn't contain any video urls. Each link contain a record id, for example <a id="120">SampleVideo1</a>. When a user clicks on particular link ajax request is send to restlet with json input of record id(120)..

Comment: Then restlet receives the request from client and get the record id(120) from request, based on record id it will get the video file path from data base and create file object with that path and stream the video data and send response to client app(ajax response) then ajax receives the response from server and set to Video tag and plays the video..that is what i want exactly ..

Comment: Thank you sir, you almost 90% covered my requirement. The video is playing successfully without any issues. If the url( http://example.com:9000/videos/testvideo) is copied and pasted into browser the video is playing but it should not. Could you please tell me how can i restrict the others accessing the video using url..

Comment: I guess this question is beyond the scope of the initial one. Some thought though. Imagine a user able to use your service. He can read the javascript code, use the diagnostic tools of the browser and read the whole request. Then nothing prevents him to play and replay the request. One solution is to protect the whole resources (web page and videos). Another is to imagine a way to give single access to a resources (using timestamped cookies, etc). I suggest you spend some time to find general solutions and I will be pleased to help implement them using Restlet (in another question).

Comment: Thank you  @Thierry Boileau. I will workout the url security issue.

Comment: First time playing video when i forward the video getting exception in server and video stucked. For suppose After completing the full video playing forward and backward are working fine.