# i have embedded videos from youtube on search, i want to display videos with the help of ajax without reloading page

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

i search any video and it display results from the youtube. now i want to display results through ajax. whenever i search for any video, it should display videos without reloading the page. i have written a little bit code of ajax. i dont know how to pass videos result in the ajax. below is the code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">

<div class="search">
<div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <form action="fetch.php" method="POST" class="form-inline">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="vid" id="vid" placeholder="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="search" id="search">Search</button>  
  </form>
  </div>
 </div>

<div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
  echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
}

?>
</div>

 </nav>

 <br>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
  $query = $_POST['vid'];
}


$API_key = '';                                                                                                         
$maxResults = 10;
$api_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&q='.urlencode($query).'&maxResults='.$maxResults.'&key='.$API_key.'';
$videoList=json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url, true));


echo "<div class='left-display'>";

  echo '<iframe id="play-video" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

echo "</div>";


echo "<div class='right-display'>";
echo "<h4>Up Next</h4>";
foreach($videoList->items as $item)
{                                                                                                                     
  if(isset($item->id->videoId))
  {                                                                      
      echo '<div id="youtube-video">
            <div>                                                                                                              
                <img class="image" width="240" height="150" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/'.$item->id->videoId.'/default.jpg" data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$item->id->videoId.' ">             
                <p>'. $item->snippet->title .'</p>
          </div>
        </div>'; 
  } 
}
echo "</div>";

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $('.image').click(function()
  {
    const value = $(this).attr("data");
   $('#play-video').attr("src", value);
  });


  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').click(function(e){

      var searchterm = $('#vid').val();

      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: fetch.php,
        data: {search, searchterm}, 
        datatype: "html",
        success: function(data){
          $('#youtube-video').html(data);
        }
      });
    })
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Are you having a specific error or problem when you run this code? What debugging have you done? We can't run it so if we can't see obvious problems just from reading it then you need to tell us the results of debugging.

Comment: i dont know how to pass the result of search in ajax, i need to know how to write code of ajax according this code. the code display the display the videos on search, now i want to display these results video reloading the page.

Comment: i have written foreach loop to display results but i dont know how to do this through ajax, how to pass these in ajax response

Comment: This is the nice example to get you start. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901507/stream-videos-in-client-app-using-ajax-and-java-restlet

Comment: @NadeemTaj OP needs a PHP solution, not a Java one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a few possible issues with your code:

1. You've written `$('#youtube-video').html(data);` to append the results of the AJAX call into your page, but there is no element called "youtube-video" ready-made in your page, so there's nowhere for the data to go. You need a ready-made element to put the results into. (Your PHP code defines an element called "youtube-video" but it only outputs it during the AJAX request, so it's there in `data` - but you haven't processed that yet so it doesn't exist in the page at the time you try to use it.)
2. Your format for sending the data is wrong - to define a property called "search" it should be `{search: searchterm}`
3. You're not fully separating the PHP code which runs when the page loads from the code which runs when AJAX is called. The PHP code which tries to search will run every time you execute the page, so you could get errors when it first loads (because `$query` won't be defined) and also the response to your AJAX would have other bits of the page mixed up in it as well (including the static HTML sections).
   Short of putting the AJAX-related PHP code into a separate file, the next best thing is to put it all into an `if` statement at the top of the script, and finish it with an `exit()` command so it doesn't output anything else it shouldn't.
4. `$query = $_POST['vid'];` looks for a parameter called "vid" which isn't being submitted b the AJAX request. You only send "search" in the AJAX request, which contains the query to search for, so you need to look for that in `$_POST` instead - i.e. `$query = $_POST['search'];`.
5. Your AJAX call sets the URL of the request to "fetch.php". It's not clear whether this is the name of the file containing the code you've shown us, or another file. But the code to search and display the videos is in the code you've shown us, so the URL needs to be the name of that file.

Here's a version of the code which resolves those problems (apart from number 5 because I can't tell if that's a mistake or not):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
  $query = $_POST['search'];
  $API_key = '';                                                                                                         
  $maxResults = 10;
  $api_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&q='.urlencode($query).'&maxResults='.$maxResults.'&key='.$API_key.'';
  $videoList = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url, true));
  echo "<div class='left-display'>";
  echo '<iframe id="play-video" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
  echo "</div>";
  echo "<div class='right-display'>";
  echo "<h4>Up Next</h4>";

  foreach($videoList->items as $item)
  {                                                                                                                     
    if(isset($item->id->videoId))
    {                                                                      
      echo '<div class="youtube-video">
            <div>                                                                                                              
                <img class="image" width="240" height="150" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/'.$item->id->videoId.'/default.jpg" data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$item->id->videoId.' ">             
                <p>'. $item->snippet->title .'</p>
          </div>
        </div>'; 
    } 
  }
  echo "</div>";
  exit();
}
?>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <div class="search">
    <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <form action="" method="POST" class="form-inline">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="search" id="vid" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" id="search">Search</button>  
      </form>
    </div>
 </div>
  <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

  <?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
  {
    echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
  }
  ?>

  </div>
 </nav>
 <br>
 <div id="videos"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 
   $('.image').click(function()
   {
     const value = $(this).attr("data");
     $('#play-video').attr("src", value);
    });

   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#search').click(function(e){
       var searchterm = $('#vid').val();
       e.preventDefault();
    
       $.ajax({
         method: "POST",
         url: fetch.php,
         data: {search: searchterm}, 
         datatype: "html",
         success: function(data){
           $('#videos').html(data);
         }
       });
     });
   });
 </script>
```